# How to pass date_trunc interval as variable into SQL query and work with a given date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a node postgres app and need to group some purchase information by days, weeks or months for a given date range (using timestampz), to be used in a chart displayed above a table showing the non-aggregated data. Thus for a table showing:

```
SELECT purchase_date, total 
FROM orders
WHERE purchase_date >= $1
  AND purchase_date <= $2;

[startDate, endDate]
```

I want to run another query using the same timestamptz range returning grouped data from solely within the bounds of that range, accounting for partial months or weeks at the edges. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc($1, purchase_date) unit_of_time,
    SUM(total)  
FROM orders
WHERE purchase_date >= $2
  AND purchase_date <= $3
GROUP BY unit_of_time
ORDER BY unit_time;

[interval, startDate, endDate]
```

The above query works correctly for when I pass in either 'month' or 'day' as the interval variable, but gives incorrect values for week, due to the way postgres is calculating the beginning of a week. So for a query with a range of 2017-07-01 00:00:00-07, 2017-08-01 00:00:00-07, 
what I want is:

```
2017-07-01T07:00:00.000Z,
2017-07-08T07:00:00.000Z,
2017-07-15T07:00:00.000Z,
2017-07-22T07:00:00.000Z,
2017-07-29T07:00:00.000Z
```

and for all of the SUM(total) associated with those groups to exactly match the SUM(total) of all the orders in July.

But what I get back is actually:

```
2017-06-26T07:00:00.000Z,
2017-07-03T07:00:00.000Z,
2017-07-10T07:00:00.000Z,
2017-07-17T07:00:00.000Z,
2017-07-24T07:00:00.000Z,
2017-07-31T07:00:00.000Z
```

So for a date range starting in very early July, it will include order data from the last few days of June because of the first week having to start on a Monday, which is not what I want. It looks like the way around this is by setting an explicit interval. Some copy pasta and experimentation led to this query, which appears to work from a few spot checks, but frankly I do not understand why (like, why '5 day'?), and am pretty confident it is the wrong approach:

```
SELECT (
  DATE_TRUNC(
    'week',
    (purchase_date :: timestamp - INTERVAL '5 day')
  ) + INTERVAL '5 day'
) AS unit_of_time,
SUM(total)
FROM orders
WHERE purchase_date >= $1
AND purchase_date <= $2
GROUP BY unit_of_time
ORDER BY unit_time;

[startDate, endDate]
```

In addition to uncertainty around the approach to interval here, I have also been unable to abstract it to a variable so that I can keep one query for day, week and month. Any ideas?

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) says: *By definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays*. You forgot to describe your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I added more detail to question.